# What tool generates diagrams from SQL Server hierarchical data?

Tags: sql-server, visualization, hierarchical-data, diagramming

Is there a tool that works with SQL Server to generate tree-like diagrams from a hierachical data model?

I am working with a large geographical hierarchy, and would like to visualize it.

Here is an example.

I have a NodeHierarchy table that stores a hierarchical relationship among nodes. Each row in the table represents a node. Each node but one has a parent node. The node that has no parent is the root if the hierarchy.

Here is how I create my table:

```
CREATE DATABASE HierarchyTest;
GO

USE HierarchyTest;
GO

CREATE TABLE NodeHierarchy (
  PK_NodeID INT NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_NodeHierarchy PRIMARY KEY,
  FK_ParentNodeID INT NULL
    CONSTRAINT FK_NodeHierarchy_NodeHierarchy FOREIGN KEY
      REFERENCES NodeHierarchy(PK_NodeID),
  Name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

I have an example hierachy of Scottish cities and venues. Scotland is the root of the hierachy. The descendants of Scotland are cities and venues. In this hiearchy, a parent 'contains' a child, so we say that e.g. "The Barrowlands is in Glasgow, and Glasgow is in Scotland".

This statement populates the NodeHierachy table with eample data:

```
INSERT INTO NodeHierarchy(PK_NodeID, FK_ParentNodeID, Name)
VALUES
  (1, NULL, N'Scotland'),
  (2, 1, N'Glasgow'),
  (3, 1, N'Edinburgh'),
  (4, 1, N'St Andrews'),
  (5, 2, N'The Barrowlands'),
  (6, 2, N'The Cathouse'),
  (7, 2, N'Carling Academy'),
  (8, 2, N'SECC'),
  (9, 2, N'King Tut''s Wah-Wah Hut'),
  (10, 3, N'Henry''s Cellar Bar'),
  (11, 3, N'The Bongo Club'),
  (12, 3, N'Sneaky Pete''s'),
  (13, 3, N'The Picture House'),
  (14, 3, N'Potterrow'),
  (15, 4, N'Aikman''s'),
  (16, 4, N'The Union'),
  (17, 4, N'Castle Sands');
```

Output of `SELECT * FROM NodeHierarchy;`:

```
PK_NodeID   FK_ParentNodeID Name
----------- --------------- ---------------------------------
1           NULL            Scotland
2           1               Glasgow
3           1               Edinburgh
4           1               St Andrews
5           2               The Barrowlands
6           2               The Cathouse
7           2               Carling Academy
8           2               SECC
9           2               King Tut's Wah-Wah Hut
10          3               Henry's Cellar Bar
11          3               The Bongo Club
12          3               Sneaky Pete's
13          3               The Picture House
14          3               Potterrow
15          4               Aikman's
16          4               The Union
17          4               Castle Sands

(17 row(s) affected)
```

In [Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) I drew this equivalent diagram:
[image: mindmap of Scottish venues]

What tool can do this for me with a minimum of manual effort?

---

**EDIT:** Originally I said that I wanted to visualize "all or part" of the hierarchy. The solution posted here visualizes the entire hierarchy unconditionally. This is fine for the small example hierarchy, but for a larger one, it may be more useful to visualize only part of it.

Because I didn't specify what I meant by "part", I have removed this from the question. I have asked about partial visualization in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462420/how-to-visualize-only-the-descendants-ancestors-and-self-of-a-node-in-a-hierarc).

Comment: +1 This is a great question. I'd like to know the answer too.

Comment: +1 I really like that you've included `CREATE DATABASE` and `INSERT` so I can cut & paste!

Comment: Thanks, Kirk. It's in the sprit of the 'short, self-contained, correct, compilable example': http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I researched the leads in Cade Roux's answer and developed a solution using GraphViz.

To understand GraphViz, first I read this [introductory article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7275) and the [Command-line Invocation](http://www.graphviz.org/content/command-line-invocation) documentation. After successfully generating graphs from the example code listing in the article, I felt confident to work with my own data.

As Cade suggested, the best way to learn GraphViz's DOT language is to write it out myself. I studied the article's examples (Listings 1, 2, and 6) and then came up with this `venues.gv` to describe my own data:

```
digraph Venues
{ 
  N1[label = "Scotland"];
  N2[label = "Glasgow"];
  N3[label = "Edinburgh"];
  N4[label = "St Andrews"];
  N5[label = "The Barrowlands"];
  N6[label = "The Cathouse"];
  N7[label = "Carling Academy"];
  N8[label = "SECC"];
  N9[label = "King Tut's Wah-Wah Hut"];
  N10[label = "Henry's Cellar Bar"];
  N11[label = "The Bongo Club"];
  N12[label = "Sneaky Pete's"];
  N13[label = "The Picture House"];
  N14[label = "Potterrow"];
  N15[label = "Aikman's"];
  N16[label = "The Union"];
  N17[label = "Castle Sands"];

  N1 -> N2;
  N1 -> N3;
  N1 -> N4;
  N2 -> N5;
  N2 -> N6;
  N2 -> N7;
  N2 -> N8;
  N2 -> N9;
  N3 -> N10;
  N3 -> N11;
  N3 -> N12;
  N3 -> N13;
  N3 -> N14;
  N4 -> N15;
  N4 -> N16;
  N4 -> N17;
}
```

I fed this to `circo`, just one of the many graph-drawing commands that are part of GraphViz, and got pleasing output:

Output of `circo -Tpng venues.gv -o venues.png`:

[image: Visualization of hierarchical venue data]

The GraphViz file is structured in two blocks. One block declares a label for each node, and the other block declares the edges of the graph.

To provide the data for each of these blocks, I created a view of `NodeHierarchy`.

This view provides the data to declare labels for nodes:

```
CREATE VIEW NodeLabels (
  Node,
  Label
)
AS
SELECT
   PK_NodeID AS Node,
   Name AS Label
FROM
  NodeHierarchy;
```

This view provides the data to declare edges between nodes:

```
CREATE VIEW Edges (
  Parent,
  Child
)
AS
SELECT
  FK_ParentNodeID AS Parent,
  PK_NodeID AS Child
FROM NodeHierarchy
WHERE FK_ParentNodeID IS NOT NULL;
```

This Powershell script called `generate-graph.ps1` selects the data from the views, transforms it into a GraphViz input, and pipes it to `circo` to produce a visualization of the full hierarchy like the one above:

```
"digraph Venues {" + (
  Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * FROM HierarchyTest.dbo.NodeLabels" | 
  ForEach-Object {"N" + $_.Node + "[label = """ + $_.Label + """];"}
) + (
  Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * FROM HierarchyTest.dbo.Edges" |
  ForEach-Object {"N" + $_.Parent + " -> N" + $_.Child + ";"}
) +
"}" | circo -Tpng -o venues.png
```

The script must be run in `sqlps` instead of `powershell` so that the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` cmdlet is available. The default working directory of `sqlps` is `SQLSERVER`, so I have to specify the drive when I run the script through `sqlps`.

This is the command I use to generate a graph like the one above:

```
sqlps C:.\generate-graph.ps1
```

This outputs a file called `venues.png` in the C working directory.

This Powershell solution feels a little inelegant, but this does what I need it to do. A more experienced Powershell programmer might be able to come up with something cleaner.

Comment: This visualizes only the entire hierarchy. For my small sample set of data, this is fine, but for a larger set of data I might want to look at only a small part of the hierarchy. I will post an updated solution that makes this possible.

Answer (score 8):

Export and run it through [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) - you don't even have to generate the hierarchy (just export nodes and edges) - just assign node names which are unique based on your NodeID column and use those same node names in the edges.

If you want something interactive, Microsoft has a [Automatic Graph Layout library](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/msagl/) which can be used from .NET.

Here's an [introduction to GraphViz](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7275).

What you are going to do is output a DOT file by exporting your SQL using a script like this: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/109885/ which will run through GraphViz and generate your picture.

The DOT syntax is relatively simple - you can write it by hand first and then generate that from SQL and simply paste it in a file or something else (like .NET or PowerShell) which reads the SQL sets and generates the file.

You can automate that with SSIS.  I made a package which wrote out the DOT file and ran graphviz on it and saved a graphiacl snapshot of our system on a daily basis.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GraphViz, and I don't know what you mean by 'export'. Can you explain the process in more detail? Thanks!

Comment: I read the introduction, written in 2004. Version 2.28 of GraphViz produces different output on some of the code listings from the version used by the author, but they still work and are a great learning aid. Thanks!

Comment: How did you implement writing out a DOT file in SSIS? I can output only flat files. I can't see any way to output a DOT file without using a script task.

Comment: @isme You can generate an set of "lines" from a SQL proc using something like this: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT '01-header' AS section, 1 AS line_num, 'digraph g' AS line UNION ALL SELECT '01-header' AS section, 2 AS line_num, '{' AS line UNION ALL SELECT '02-body' AS section, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY nodeid) AS line_num, 'node' + nodeid AS line FROM nodes UNION ALL ...) ORDER BY section, line_number` - now you have an ordered output of "lines", just write the "line" column as the line in the flat file.  Or write a flat file and prepend/append with a batch file or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for that SSIS trickery, but in the meantime I wrote a Powershell script to achieve the same. I will publish my entire solution as an answer.